# Set Rails Variable to Different Values for Different Capistrano Environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, environment-variables, capistrano

I have a rails app which is set up to deploy with Capistrano to one of two different servers (depending on which the user chooses to deploy to). I want to create an environment variable for the rails app which changes depending on which server the website is deployed to.

In my Capistrano deploy (config/deploy.rb) file, I have a variable "stages" that has the two options for the user to deploy to:

```
set :stages, %w(production staging)
```

I have tried to use this variable in an if statement in my environment (config/environment.rb) file to set the variable like so:

```
if (:stages == "staging")
    ENV['GLOBAL_EMAIL'] = "email1@domain.com"
else
    ENV['GLOBAL_EMAIL'] = "email2@domain.com"
end
```

However, when I test this, rails fails to render `#{ENV['GLOBAL_EMAIL']}` (as far as I can tell because the variable is not set or reachable.

My question is if there is a reason that :stages is not reachable, and also if there is a way/better way to set the variable according to the environment?

Note that even though one is called staging and one is called production, both environments deploy the production environment of rails (not test and production environments of rails), thus I cannot do a test to see which environment rails is running to then set the variable.

Comment: In ruby `:stages` is a symbol.  Have you tried `stages`?  Also, new versions of capistrano typically have a deploy/stage1.rb and deploy/stage2.rb structure so you never have to do this kind of if/else around the stage you're on.  What version of Cap are you running?

Comment: I am using version 2.13.5 and I do have two different deploy, one for each environment, and putting the variable in there does make a lot more sense. Pardon my ignorance on this, but I am now trying to put 'set :email_var, "email@domain.com"', in each of my deploy files (for each environment), but when I test this and try to access email_var, I get an "undefined local variable or method" error. I thought that, by default, the variable set in the deploy files was global in scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution I ended up with was to create a file external from my Capistrano deploy (for instance in /home/[user]/.var/.emails) on each server where each file contains just the desired email (e.g. `email1@domain.com`). Then in environments.rb:

```
ENV['GLOBAL_EMAIL'] = begin IO.read("/home/[user]/.vars/.email") rescue "" end
```

Answer (score 3):

For starters you are trying to equate a symbol with a string, which will always return false.

Also within capistrano, to get the environment your deploying in you want the `stage` variable. This variable is only available after loading and not when the file is read by ruby. What this means is that you need to provide a block that gets lazy loaded. The problem is that these are evaluated in the context of setting a local variable such as `deploy_to`.

```
set(:deploy_to) { "/var/www/#{application}/#{stage}" }
```

This is a common setup within my deploy scripts where staging and production are deployed to the same server.

You could possibly try something like:

```
set(:global_email) do
  if stage == 'production'
    ENV['GLOBAL_EMAIL'] = 'email1@example.com'
  else
    ENV['GLOBAL_EMAIL'] = 'email2@example.com'
  end
end
```

Or another way of handling this is to use the deploy stage specific files.

```
# config/deploy/production.rb
ENV['GLOBAL_EMAIL'] = 'email1@example.com'

# config/deploy/staging.rb
ENV['GLOBAL_EMAIL'] = 'email2@example.com'
```

---

### Update

I hadn't noticed the question mentioned rendering the value in Rails. This of course has nothing to do with Rails, nor is anything set in a Capistrano config file available when Rails is initialized since capistrano should really be only available in development environments.

A proper way to do this would be using a rails initalizer and setting the variable when Rails boots up.

```
# config/initializer/global_email.rb

if Rails.env.production?
  GLOBAL_EMAIL = 'email1@example.com'
else
  GLOBAL_EMAIL = 'email2@example.com'
end
```

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions but the problem seems to be that no matter how I set the variables in the deploy files, those variables cannot be read in a rails view. Either nothing appears in the view where the variable should be, or I get an error about an undefined local variable.

Comment: Oh, i didnt realize you were trying to access this from Rails. In that case you can't do it this way because capistrano has nothing to do with Rails. Stuff like this belongs in config files or a Rails initializer.